# Rails 3.0 / net-ldap - works in irb, but not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ldap

I've looked around and can't seem to find the answer to this... I'm trying to use net-ldap with rails.

in irb, I can run a quick bind and it works:

```
irb(main):003:0> ldap_con = Net::LDAP.new({:host => 'myhost.ad',
irb(main):004:2*       :base => 'DC=myhost,DC=ad',
irb(main):005:2*       :port => 389,:auth=>{:method=>:simple,:username => 'bsharpe@myhost.ad',
irb(main):006:3*       :password => 'letmein' } } )
=> #<Net::LDAP:0x292089f0 @host="myhost.ad", @open_connection=nil, @encryption=nil, @auth={:password=>"letmein", :method=>:simple, :username=>"bsharpe@myhost.ad"}, @verbose=false, @port=389, @base="DC=myhost,DC=ad">
irb(main):007:0> ldap_con.bind
=> true
```

but if i run the app i get

```
no such file to load -- net/ldap
```

which is from my `require net/ldap`
I checked `$LOAD_PATH` and it does contain `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ldap-0.1.1/lib`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding: require 'rubygems' before require 'net/ldap
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'
```

ruby version 1.8.7 and net/ldap(0.3.1)